# How do i run my Python Webscraping code with Kotlin

Tags: python, java, kotlin, pycharm

Im working on a tool that downloads files from websites. I wrote a Python code for this now how do i execute this code with Kotlin? Are there any easy ways?

(I have to do it in Kotlin but I don't know how to download something from a website so I use python)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look into this. It's written for java, but since Kotlin and Java are interoperable it will probably work.

https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/

Answer (score 0):

Python -> Kotlin isn't a straightforward conversion, especially with HTTP libraries. Try [Ktor](https://ktor.io/), a library built for web requests in Kotlin.